# How do i run a cronjob to run every 3 hours on the 59 minute

Tags: cron

Hello so i want to run my script every 3th hour but with the  "0 */3 * * *" i want it to run -1 minute before that so

- 23:59
- 02:59
- 05:59
- 08:59
- 11:59
- 14:59
- 17:59
- 20:59

Comment: The first element is the minute. `59 */3 * * *`

Comment: `59 */3 * * *` will run the job at 0:59, 3:59, 6:59, ...  If you want the job to run at 2:59, 5:59, 8:59, ... then use `59 2-23/3 * * *`